# One ViewModel or (Equivalent) per RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-lifecycle

There are tons of tutorials on how to get a simple RecyclerView going, but now my `ViewHolder` logic becomes less and less simple.
Ideally I would have one instance of `MyItemViewModel` per `ViewHolder`, so I can separate UI related helpers. Is this at all possible?

I tried inflating and passing a `binding` like this:

(in `RecyclerView.Adapter.onCreateViewHolder`)

```
val binding = MyViewBinding.inflate(
  LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
return MyViewHolder(binding)
```

But when I access `binding.viewModel` in `MyViewHolder.setItem(item: Item)` called via `RecyclerView.Adapter.onBindViewHolder` later, it is always `null`.

Any help? Can/should I instatiate one `Fragment`(`Activity`) per `Item`/`ViewHolder` so I can use `ViewModelProviders`? Is there sth similar to `ViewModel` that I should rather use?

Comment: Its possible to create a RecyclerView with multiple ViewHolder . This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type/51153083#51153083

Comment: this might help https://android.jlelse.eu/dealing-with-asynchronous-data-flow-in-recyclerview-items-model-view-presenter-approach-using-476420bfa22f

Comment: @RohitSingh thanks! It seems the trade-off of RecyclerView is the inability of declaring content in the view.

Comment: I did not understand the trade-off ? What are you exactly suggesting? Was the suggested link helpful ?

Comment: Yes, very helpful! That's why I upvoted.  I would still prefer to declare bindings in the view, not in the Adapter/ViewHolder, that is what I mean with trade-off: it seems you can not use declarative binding with RecyclerView.